# Empty folders after fitting using VOSM (Vision Open Statistical Models)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to develop an Active Appearance model using the VOSM package (http://www.visionopen.com/downloads/open-source-software/vosm/). I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 64b and use OpenCV-2.4.8, Boost-1.55 and VOSM-0.33.

I have successfully trained the model using facial databases, and have the trained data stored in a subfolder. When I try to test the AAM fitting on some test images, there are no saved files, but the terminal output indicates the fitting process has completed properly.

Command: `test_smfitting -o trained_data/ -t "AAM_BASIC" -i images/test_2/ -r "true" -s "true"`

output:

```
detection times = 5
Average Interation Times = 0
Averaget Detection time (in ms) = 0
```

There are output folders created named after the .jpg files, but they are empty.
How do I solve this?